# HuggingFace Trainer max_step to set for streaming dataset

Tags: huggingface, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-trainer

The `max_steps` argument of [TrainingArguments](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.max_steps) is `num_rows_in_train / per_device_train_batch_size * num_train_epochs` when using streaming datasets of Huggingface?

- num_rows_in_train is total number of records in the training dataset
- per_device_train_batch_size is the batch size
- num_train_epochs is the number of epochs to run

As in [Streaming dataset into Trainer: does not implement **len**, max_steps has to be specified](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/streaming-dataset-into-trainer-does-not-implement-len-max-steps-has-to-be-specified/32893/5), training with a streaming dataset requires `max_steps` instead of `num_train_epochs`.

According to the documents, it is set to **the total number of training steps** which should be number of total mini-batches.

- [max_steps](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.max_steps)

> If set to a positive number, **the total number of training steps** to perform. Overrides num_train_epochs.

For a small dataset of 2048 rows in the train split, set the training arguments as below.

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="bloom_finetuned",
    max_steps=2048 * 3,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01, 
    fp16=True,
    no_cuda=False,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
)
```

However, the training shows huge number of epochs.

```
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 6,144
  Num Epochs = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807      <-----
  Instantaneous batch size per device = 1
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 1
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 6,144
  Number of trainable parameters = 559,214,592
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to the source code in Huggingface [trainer.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7ee995fd9c692761c4601ddbffa2ac2ec9f27b0b/src/transformers/trainer.py#L1603-L1609)
here.

Take a look at this:

```py
# Setting a very large number of epochs so we go as many times as necessary over the iterator.
num_train_epochs = sys.maxsize
```

So if you are using a streaming dataset, the value will be set to "a large number", which is **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** in your example. But I think this is just a number for **enough** iterations, which will be restricted by `max_steps` in the situation.

And look at another lines in this part:

```py
num_update_steps_per_epoch = len_dataloader // args.gradient_accumulation_steps
num_update_steps_per_epoch = max(num_update_steps_per_epoch, 1)

max_steps = math.ceil(args.num_train_epochs * num_update_steps_per_epoch)
```

This piece of code is used when the dataset is **non-streaming**. However, you can refer to the logic it used. Assume you know **the number of samples**, **batch size**, **gradient_accumulation_steps** and **number of epochs**, I think the `max_steps` should be calculated as:

```py
max_steps = (num_samples // batch_size) // gradient_accumulation_steps * epochs
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).